# Using IBDesignable and prepareForInterfaceBuilder with a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have a subclass of `UIView` called `MyView` that I am creating.

In it there is a `UILabel` (this is added in code not in InterfaceBuilder for reasons).

I then have a property on `MyView` called `color`.

What I'd like is to have Interface Builder be able to select the `color` and also to then display the label with the font set to that color.

In my code I have...

```
@IBDesignable class MyView: UIView {

    private let textLabel = UILabel()

    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = .blackColor() {
        didSet {
            textLabel.textColor = color
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        initialSetup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

       initialSetup()
    }

    private func initialSetup() -> Void {
        self.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

        textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        addSubview(textLabel)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        textLabel.frame = bounds
    }

    // I have no idea what I'm doing here?!
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        // should I create a label specifically for here?
        // or should I use the property textLabel?

        textLabel.text = "Hello, world!" // setting place holder IB text?
        textLabel.textColor = color
        textLabel.font = .systemFontOfSize(21)
        textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        // do I need to add sub view?
    }

}
```

**IBInspectable**

In IB I can see the color property there and I can set it. Annoyingly it takes a default value of .clearColor() though not the color I set in code. Is there a way to fix that?

**IBDesignable**

When I put the view into InterfaceBuilder it shows all the inspectable properties but nothing is shown in the actual view.

When I run it it all works fine. I'd just like to be able to get something working (other than drawRect) in IB. I'm finding a distinct lack of documentation though.

**Edit - Warnings**

I just noticed that I'm getting build errors / warnings saying...

> warning: IB Designables: Ignoring user defined runtime attribute for key path "color" on instance of "UIView". Hit an exception when attempting to set its value: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key color.

This will probably change the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the code from your question into a new app, added the view and set the property and it worked just fine.

The error you're seeing suggests that at some point you've changed the view back to a plain UIView in the identity inspector (the user defined attributes remain in that case).

[image]

Comment: Well, currently I'm getting a "Segmentation Fault: 11" when trying to run so no idea what is going on. That could be the cause of this. Glad to know I got the actual code right though. I did install Xcode 4 (reasons) today so I wonder if that install has messed around with compilers or something?! Thanks though. Will keep my Swift project :D

Comment: OMLG! The seg fault was because I used `.clearColor()` in an attribute instead of `UIColor.clearColor()` but there were no errors showing in code. Anyway, all is working now :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When **color** is set you need to update the textLabel property like below using a didSet

```
@IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() {
    didSet {
        textLabel.textColor = color
    }
}
```

Comment: I added that. But I just noticed I'm also getting warnings... "Ignoring User Defined runtime attribute for keyPath color..." Added this into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am using swift 2.0 and in my case was missing **dynamic** property. Final code:

```
@IBInspectable dynamic var radius:CGFloat = 2.0 {
    didSet {
     //   setNeedsDisplay()
        layer.cornerRadius = radius

    }
}
```

Find out error during build for **IB Designables**: http://lamb-mei.com/537/xcode-ibdesignables-ignoring-user-defined-runtime-attribute-for-key-path-bordercolor-on-instance-of-uiview-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-bordercolor/